# solr/lucene scoring by percentage of text matched?

Tags: solr, lucene

Fairly new to Solr/Lucene. I have a simple requirement, not sure if it is easy to config solr to do this.

assume all the documents only has one text field, not tokenized.

when a query comes in, I want the result sort by percentage of text matched(contain). percentage is calculated by `len(query)/len(matched text field)`

for example, there are three documents, the text fields are below:
doc1: abcdefghij
doc2: abcdefgh
3: abc

if the search term is 'cde', doc 1 and doc 2 are matched( text field contains search term).
for doc 1, percentage match = 3/10=30%
for doc 2, percentage match = 3/8=37.5%

so the result should be:
doc2
doc1

does this make sense? how to implement it using solr?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override Lucene scoring.

Extend [org.apache.lucene.search.DefaultSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.html), defining your custom scoring algorithm.

A lot of the methods of DefaultSimilarity you'll probably want to just stub, like idf (just return 1), so that the more complex elements of scoring don't effect your results.

Then add a line in your schema.xml in solr, configuring it to use your scoring class, like:

```
<similarity class="com.mycompany.MySimilarity" />
```

Here's a page with some information on how scoring works, check here: [Lucene Scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/scoring.html).  Some resources there on adding custom functionality as well, which will probably help in putting together a usable Similarily class.

Honestly, though, especially if you're new to Lucene/Solr, you would probably be much better served getting some experience with the default scoring.  It works quite well, and you remove a lot of valuable functionality by throwing it out.

EDIT:

Note, this provides a possible (though not pretty) way to implement the Similarity.  Look further down for another way.  You'll still need a custom Similarity, but it's a simpler one.

Okay, here's a stab at it.  I haven't tested it (not really in a position to do so right now), but perhaps it will point you in the right direction.

Probably the easiest way to get at this is to store a norm for each field that encodes the length of the term.  To do this override computeNorm, and return the inverse of the length, taken from the second argument.

In order to compute the precise scoring you have specified, you need to get access to the matching query term, or it's length.  Neither are really easy.  You might find a way, or you could manually pass that value into the similarity class.  Since you just need to get the values out in the order you specified, another way to state your requirement is "order results from shortest to longest".  Which we've already accomplished with computeNorm.

Then you just stub out the rest, resulting something along these lines:

```
float computeNorm(String field, FieldInvertState state) {
    int length = state.getOffset() - state.getPosition();
    return 1.0 / (float)length;
}
float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
    return 1;
}
float idf(int docFreq, int numDocs) {
    return 1;
}
float tf(float freq) {
    return 1;
}
float queryNorm(float sumOfSquaredWeights) {
    return 1;
}
float sloppyFreq(int distance) {
    return 1;
}
float lengthNorm(string fieldName, int numTerms) {
    return 1;
}
```

Note:  the norm is calculated when the document is indexed, so this Similarity must be used when inserting documents for it to be effective.  Query time will be too late to set the norm.  It is also very approximate, due to compression.

AN EASIER WAY (maybe):

You know, now that I think about it, since the same ordering is acquired by just sorting shortest to longest, you could do this without the complexity of a new Similarity class.
When you add documents you could just apply a field-level boost accomplishing the same thing.  Just boost each of these terms by 1/length, or some similar method.

if you insert abcde, apply a boost of 1/5 to the field.

Having done that, you could even query like 'term:abc*^3', and that would allow you to get the percentage score you previously indicated (althoug the effect is much the same either way, with only one query term).

I think you should be able to just stub out everything in your CustomSimilarity if you score using boosts like this.  'idf' and 'tf' are probably all you really need to worry about overriding in this case.

Comment: Can you add more information as to how the user can handle the specific issue by Overriding the Similarity class ?

Comment: @femtoRgon, Thanks for the reply. Is there any example that shows how to override scoring? Yes I totally understand that the default scoring worked very well. It is a business requirement for a project and I would like to see if Solr can handle this.